# Can a graph be non-planar in 3d?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am currently reading Trudeau's introductory book on Graph Theory and have just come across the concept of planar and non-planar graphs. The definition reads: 'A graph is planar if it is isomorphic to a graph that has been drawn in a *plane* without edge-crossings'. My question is, if the definition is changed slightly, and we replace *'plane'* with *'3D space'*, does this lead to all possible finite graphs being planar? Or to put it more simply (I think), is there a graph which cannot be drawn without edge crossings in 3D space? And if not how can one prove that such a graph would not exist?

I apologize if this question is trivial; I thought of graphs only as representations of functions until yesterday.

Comment: Yes, this is very much known. Lie all vertices on a straight line and each edge in a plane, passing through the line (specific for that edge, i.e. one plane for each edge). Can you Imagine the construction? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin : This is a book embedding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding) right?

Comment: A sort of)${}{}$

Comment: If the graph is finite (as is often more or less implicitly assumed) or countable, it is going to be easy to put it 3D. If you allow "pathologically" large sets $V$ as vertex sets, eventually it is going to be impossible. Let us say $V=2^\mathbb{R}$ (and for edges, we can just take "all", i.e. a complete graph), then there are more vertices than there are points in the 3D continuum $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, such objects are not usually considered "graphs", even if many definitions do not exclude them.

Comment: One idea similar to planar graphs but in 3D space are the [*linkless embeddable graphs*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkless_embedding). There are some result (e.g. the characterization of graphs with small Colin de Verdière number) that suggest that these are the appropriate analogues of planar graphs in 3D.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, I'd like to point out that the term "graph" has two different meanings in mathematics. One is a structure comprising vertices and edges (as here). The other is the set of tuples that represents a relation. For example the graph of the unit circle is $\{ (x,y) : x^2+y^2=1 \}$. The context is needed for you to determine which meaning is intended, and the two meanings have no link to one another.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A finite graph has a finite vertex set $V=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$. Arrange these vertices as points $v_k=(k,0,0)$ $(1\leq k\leq n)$ on the $x$-axis of  ${\mathbb R}^3$. Some pairs $v_i$, $v_j$ $(i\ne j)$ are joined by an edge. Assume there are $N\leq{n\choose2}$ edges. Choose $N$ different planes containing the $x$-axis, and draw each occurring edge $\{v_i,v_j\}$ as a half circle connecting $v_i$ with $v_j$ in one of these planes. The $N$ edges will then not intersect.

By the way: Graphs of functions and graphs studied here have nothing in common. It's a semantic accident that the two completely different things have obtained the same name.

Answer (score 20):

To extend Christian's construction: you can in fact even embed the vertices of your graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that all $N$ edges of the graph are straight lines, and this construction is close to trivial: just make all of the coordinates of the vertices [*algebraically independent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence) of each other. You can show that this is possible by a dimensionality/counting argument (essentially, given any finite collection of real numbers, there are only countably many numbers in algebraic dependence with them, so there are uncountably many algebraically independent choices that can be made at each step). The key difference between space and the plane here is that while any two non-parallel straight lines will intersect in the plane, lines in space have an additional 'degree of freedom' that means that they need to satisfy certain conditions in order to intersect, and those conditions can be expressed algebraically in terms of the endpoints of segments of the two lines.

Comment: A popular choice is to place the vertices on the moment curve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_curve